# Differences between GTK VS WinForm code. Does GTK has enough feature than winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, gtk

I am a newbie at c# programming. I would like to know the basic difference between `gtk` and `winform` applications..
Actually, I am a linux user. My OS doesn't support `Visual Studio community`. So, it will be a great help, if you would like to know whether I should use VM and download visual studio community on it or use gtk form on monodevelop instead of winform.

And also, I would like to know if the code of `gtk` and `winform` are same or not.

Can I be able to run gtk type project on windows ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinForms is a GUI toolkit API designed by Microsoft for .NET and is implemented on top of native Windows APIs and Windows controls. The Mono project made a cross platform implementation of the [WinForms](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) APIs (a port) that can run on all widely used desktop operating systems (Linux / Windows / MacOS). I have never used MonoDevelop but I have heard that it is actually very good, you should give it a try!

[Gtk](https://www.gtk.org/) is an open source, cross platform GUI toolkit (Linux / Windows / MacOS). It is usable from many languages thanks to the numerous language bindings available. For C# language there is [Gtk#](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/). Like Mono it also has an active community where you can ask questions https://discourse.gnome.org/c/platform

To decide you can read here: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/